# Floating multiple divs down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu that becomes a dropdown when it is in mobile, and floats right when it is desktop, therefore all my divs are reversed in order since float right wouldn't work otherwise

```
      <div class="menu active">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="menu-item whitelist">
            <a href="#">Join Whitelist</a>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">FAQ</a>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">Team</a>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">Token</a>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-btn">
          <a class="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

my question is how can I make then "float" downwards in my dropdown menu so they are in the right order? Or is it better to change how they act when it's in desktop mode?

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Comment: you could use display:flex instead of float

Comment: `inline-block` would probably simplify things. Floats are notoriously troublesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want them in the correct order to begin with, then use `display:inline-block` to make them all go on a single line for desktop.

Hard to tell without seeing any css or design, but that sounds reasonable.